# Laravel logout not working

Tags: php, laravel, session, logout

I'm trying simple logout functionality in laravel 5.2 but don't really understand where am I wrong. It would be great is someone can help.

here's **Route**

```
Route::get('logout', 'loginController@getLogout');
```

**loginController** `getLogout` method:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    //$this->auth->logout();
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

**link** in view that uses this function:

```
<a href="{{url('logout')}}">Logout</a>
```

**session store** code:

```
$request->session()->put('name', $username['name']);
```

**AuthController** constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
}
```

When user clicks on the logout link, it does redirect to root page but doesn't really destroy session or logout. It isn't requiring login to view pages (which it should).

Comment: Try to put a die("Stop here!"); at the begging of getLogout function to see if you are going though it. I'm not 100% but maybe you need to put '/' in url('/logout').

Comment: yes die does work. And without die, it does redirect to '/' (root page)
My guess is maybe i"m using session()->put that is why it doesn't remove session with: Session::flush()? Can that be an issue?

Comment: According with the doc, flush() removes all data in session. I'm using this route in my laravel apps. Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout'); and normally it works :)

Answer (score 1):

> I too had the same problem and i have rectified by Method 1 and i had reference using Method 2.

**Method 1:**

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

Or **Method 2:**
or in AuthController constructor add

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
}
```

Hope so this will clear up your Error. I had the same problem and i did like this alone

**Session Destroy must be used like this**

```
Session::forget('name');
$request->session()->flush(); // in your Controller
```

Comment: hello, I've already method 2 in place, still facing the problem

Comment: still no luck! i did:
       Session::forget('name');
        $request->session()->flush();
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');

Comment: Uss this and try `Route::get('logout', [ 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout', 'as' => 'logout' ]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the route in routes.php with this:

```
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

And for the logout route I use:

```
{{ url('/logout') }}
```

Normally this works, if you need to use a different controller for something especial, try to use the:

```
$request->session()->flush()
```

in the controller. 
Following the Laravel 5.2 documentation -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session.

Other approximation, try to modify the order in your controller, maybe it will work. According to the doc, Auth:logout() will clean all user auth data, then you can clean the other session data.

```
public function getLogout()
{
    //$this->auth->logout();
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Mmm. Something is messing up this. :D Have you commented the old route and put the new one just behind it? Have you got any other route with logout?

Comment: yes, i did comment the old route and put new. And no other route with logout

Comment: What about changing the order of the operations in the controller function, please check the updated answer.